# Empty profile pic when trying to get a bigger size using Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all user's profile pictures in Facebook using Graph API.
Ans I came across a weird problem, when I am asking somthing like this:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/" + d.get(i) + "/picture?width=100&height=100";
```

It reutrn an empty profile for half of the images, but when I decreas the width and height all is ok again. Someone have an idea what causes it to happen?

I want to get bigger images for better resolution.

And when I type the URL in my browser it says it is correct and displays the images in the given size.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

https://graph.facebook.com/{id}?fields=picture.type(large)